# matching german umlaut with regexp correctly twice

Tags: regex, perl, diacritics, strawberry-perl

i have a small script, which match via regexp if a string contains german umlauts like äöüß. In the first regexp match everything is working fine, but if i check the same string again it does not longer match correctly. The file itself is encoded as utf8 and i am also including the utf8 module.

this is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use utf8;
use Log4Perl::logger_helper qw( init_logger get_logger_and_trace );

my $strings = ["ä", "ae","ö", "oe", "ü", "ue", "ß", "ss"];

my $logger = init_logger(
    log_file_path => $0 . '.log'
);    # init_logger variables are all optional

foreach my $string (@$strings) {
    for(1..5) {
        if ( $string =~ /[\x{00C4}\x{00E4}\x{00D6}\x{00F6}\x{00DC}\x{00FC}\x{00DF}]/gi ) {
            $logger->info("umlauts match $string");
        }
        else {
            $logger->info("no umlauts $string");
        }
    }
 }
```

and this is the output:

```
umlauts match ä
no umlauts ä
umlauts match ä
no umlauts ä
umlauts match ä
no umlauts ae
no umlauts ae
no umlauts ae
no umlauts ae
no umlauts ae
umlauts match ö
no umlauts ö
umlauts match ö
no umlauts ö
umlauts match ö
no umlauts oe
no umlauts oe
no umlauts oe
no umlauts oe
no umlauts oe
umlauts match ü
no umlauts ü
umlauts match ü
no umlauts ü
umlauts match ü
no umlauts ue
no umlauts ue
no umlauts ue
no umlauts ue
no umlauts ue
umlauts match ß
no umlauts ß
umlauts match ß
no umlauts ß
umlauts match ß
no umlauts ss
no umlauts ss
no umlauts ss
no umlauts ss
no umlauts ss

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tested it on different OS with different version of strawberry perl, also latest version (strawberry-perl-5.30.0.1-64bit-portable) is shown this error for me.

Any idea why it is matching alterating correctly? If i do the same with multiple index operations it is working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `global` flag. Remove it.

Comment: hi, thx this is working. Do you have a explanation for this behaviour? it looks like the match pointer is saved?

Answer (score 3):

As [@daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46395/daxim) explained, the global flag `/g` causes havoc here.

From [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), important section highlighted in **bold**:

> In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match,
>   returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.
>   The position after the last match can be read or set using the [`pos()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)
>   function. **A failed match** normally **resets the
>   search position to the beginning of the string**, but you can avoid
>   that by adding the `/c` modifier (for example, `m//gc`). Modifying the
>   target string also resets the search position.

Since you repeatedly search within the same `$string` (without modifying it in between), each second search continues after the last successful match, resulting in a failure and resetting the search position for the next search.

See also "Global matching" in [Using regular expressions in Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl):

> The modifier `/g` stands for global matching and allows the matching
>   operator to match within a string as many times as possible. In scalar
>   context, successive invocations against a string will have `/g` jump
>   from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it
>   goes along. You can get or set the position with the [`pos()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)
>   function.

ciao, daniel :-)